# what is difference between MS SQL server and MySQL server

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server-2008

if you read some MVP's blog for watching out the difference then they always can talk SQL server  because why they tell about Mysql whenever they itself not used My SQL server or itself not interested in Mysql. [you are amazed then they write everywhere that when someone talk them for opensource database then they answer MS SQL server express. ha ha [nice joke they make]

if you talk with someone who use MySQL then they difficult to answer because they not used MS SQL so tehy first not give answer or very hard to explain.

so i need to know about what the thing a have and another not. are their anyone can explain the pros and cons of using both type of database.

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ms+sql+vs+mysql 18.6 million results

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/move_from_microsoft_SQL_Server.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would recommend reading
   [this](http://www.tometasoftware.com/MySQL-5-vs-Microsoft-SQL-Server-2005.asp) (point of view SQL) to give you an
   idea

   2-[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/move_from_microsoft_SQL_Server.html)
   to view the other side (Mysql)

   3- And finally some [differences](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/SQL-Server-vs-MySQL)